# Yahoo OAuth Error 401 Consumer Key Unknown

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, request, yahoo

I am trying to get a request token from Yahoo by making a POST request to the following URL: 
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token

I am making the request in the following way:

```
int randomNumber = rand();

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"oauth_consumer_key": YahooConsumerKey,
                             @"oauth_signature_method": @"plaintext",
                             @"oauth_signature": YahooConsumerSecret,
                             @"oauth_version": @"1.0",
                             @"xoauth_lang_pref": @"en_us",
                             @"oauth_callback": @"oob",
                             @"oauth_timestamp": [self getTimeStamp],
                             @"oauth_nonce": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", randomNumber]};

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager POST:@"https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

The problem is that I keep getting the error 401 with the explanation that the consumer key is unknown. I have pasted the consumer key from where I've created my project, so I really don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to manually create the request URL with GET parameters and paste it in the browser? I'm currently working with Yahoo OAuth 1.0a and it's working fine for me. Can you print out the full request in GET see how it looks like?

Comment: Yeah, the request will look something like this [link](https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_callback=oob&oauth_consumer_key=dj0yJmk9bEo2TmFVbTBZMlNvJmQ9WVdrOU5VZHVTWFpJTkdNbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1lOA--&oauth_nonce=16807&oauth_signature=621f893e5e295f8efba1c76a4e4eb8fcb9371e0e&oauth_signature_method=plaintext&oauth_timestamp=1407351169&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_lang_pref=en_us) @michaelchum

Comment: Try the link in my answer, you just need to append `%26` to your consumer secret. I am also working on a revamped iOS SDK for Yahoo OAuth 1.0a should be released soon!

Comment: @michaelchum the request works, but when I'm trying to make the request with AFNetworking it adds %2526 at the end of the string, so the request won't work. I'm trying to make the request the classic way right know with NSMutableURLRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request looks good. Try appending `@"%26"` to your `YahooConsumerSecret` string. Here's your request [link](https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_callback=oob&oauth_consumer_key=dj0yJmk9bEo2TmFVbTBZMlNvJmQ9WVdrOU5VZHVTWFpJTkdNbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1lOA--&oauth_nonce=16807&oauth_signature=621f893e5e295f8efba1c76a4e4eb8fcb9371e0e%26&oauth_signature_method=plaintext&oauth_timestamp=1407351169&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_lang_pref=en_us) with the fix, it seems to be working!

When using `plaintext` as `oauth_signature_method` you need to append `%26` at the end of your `oauth_signature` according to the Yahoo docs.